# Extra characters after echo in php

Tags: php

Getting started in PHP, but even with a "Hello world" I'm running into problems ...

Here's my page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php 
        echo "<p>Hello world.<br /> </p>" ;
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

But instead of just 'Hello world.' I get

```
Hello world.

" ; ?>
```

What gives?

FWIW, I'm using XAMPPlite (which is an Apache 2.5.8 with a PHP 5.3.1 on Win XP).

Comment: Well, starting with PHP the first and most important thing to understand: PHP do not draw pixels on the browser's screen but merely prints out an HTML **text**. The picture you see in the browser IS NOT what PHP prints out. ALWAYS see **page source** instead of rendered image. It's dramatically different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should save the file with a .php extension, not as .html.

Comment: And be sure parsing php is enabled, i mean view your script from internet browser by your ip, not just openning file in IE or something

Answer (score 3):

it is not parsing it as php, it is just outputting it as html
i.e. it treats

```
<?php 
        echo "<p>
```

as an (unknown) tag.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty odd..

Did you try taking the space out before the semicolon?

Comment: Yes, the space was a "residue" of trying a few things out.

Comment: That was my first thought, too, but spacing doesn't matter in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code, I'd look for the problems elsewhere. Is the server running/configured correctly, is Apache configured for php, (is your file extention php?).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the script only gets processed in a web server before sending the output to a browser. You must be trying to run it on the client side, try putting it into a web folder on a web server. You're code has nothing wrong.